# Problems with OpenSSH on Linux

Tags: linux-mint

I have some problems with ssh and connection two computers one of them windows and Linux mint 15. When i put ip address to **ech0** with command **ifconfig ech0 192.168..** on Linux. The coming register ip and i can see my register ip after open ssh the gone and my another computer which is windows can't inter in my pc with ssh. Why this problem coming? Is it possibility to solve this?
Thank you for all hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first What you want to do?
1.connect from Linux Machine to Windows Machine or vise versa?
2.You want to use SSH connection ?

```
from Windows ---->> to Linux With SSH (using SSH protocol)
```

a.install putty on windows
b.Edit SSH config file 
`~/.ssh/config`
 on you Linux machine to accept INCOMING connection and also set the port or use the default port 
SSH config file is a text file a command per line. if the # is before a line, that line would not read by OpenSSH and it is like you removed it from the config file.
3.open putty in your windows machine and create a new connection profile.
give it the ip of your Linux machine and the Port.
then press connect
if the connection is successful then you get a command prompt much like the console on your linux machine.

Comment: Sorry i did not describe perfect. Sorry about that. It's not problem with windows it's ok. Only problem with Linux OS. Because when i want to changes ip with command ifconfig eth0 .... then show me my ip some i changed. After this log in sshd. And windows OS just enter they gone. Windows can't come in Linux OS. Why because i have some security firewall or maybe some programs interfere or i don't know exactly. Please help me. Thanks for all hints.

Comment: When I wanna open ssh with command (Linux machine) `sshd`. The come error like: `sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path`

Comment: Tell me this your destination is a Linux mchine yes?

Comment: and also you have firewall on your window machine yes?